# hide alphabetic letters only from paragraph texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a large dynamically generated paragraph text which includes alphabetic and decimal letters.

**Question:** I want to hide all alphabetic letters from my paragraph and need to display only decimal letters.

For example:

```
<div class="mytexts">
Some texts stackoverflow 8595 google yahooo 44871 facebok  blaaa blaaa 445 blaa blaaa 
</div>
```

Results will be: **8595 44871 445**

any idea.?

thanks...

Comment: Then why you need to write there

Comment: You could examine each "word" in the DIV (each white-space-delimited chunk) and wrap any chunk that does not consist exclusively of 0-9 in a <span class="t">; the class would have display:none CSS.

Comment: @Tim... this texts added not admin, its site visiting user's added texts, we don't know what they added, and how many words, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.mytexts').text().replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FMZhZ/1/)

Comment: Didn't downvote, but your solution keeps the spaces between the words.

Comment: Yes in his answer also spaces are there

Comment: But it keeps **all** spaces

Comment: @PSR your above answer when alert function its working fine, but without alerts its not working for me...

Answer (score 1):

I would use Javascript - it's the language of any browser:

```
var foo = bar.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Comment: That omits the spaces though, you'd get 859544871445 .

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution which handles all the cases.

- Replace all non-digit characters with ' ' (space)
- Replace multiple occurrence of spaces with one.
- Remove beginning and ending space

Demo Link: [Working Example at JSbin](http://jsbin.com/aloxim/3/edit)

```
var text = $('.mytexts').text();
text = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ' ')
            .replace(/ +/g, ' ')
            .replace(/^ /, '')
            .replace(/ $/, '');

 $('.mytexts').text(text);
```